# action bar for android browser

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-actionbar, menuitem

I am creating a personal browser app.i want to add edittext,back_button,forward_button and home_button on action bar. But when I set the EditText on action bar,then it was not visible. Then I removed the action bar and set the toolbar so that it was working well. But when I set back_button, forward_button and home_button in it, it was not visible. Then I again add the action bar. But it is now looking like a screenshot below.what is wrong in my codind? please suggest me .this is my screenshot
[image]

and i want to set like this
[image]

this is my style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

this is my toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:hint="search"
        android:background="#ffffff" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my edittext.xml(extra)

```
EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/action_address_bar"
android:layout_width="180dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="MY"
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
android:inputType="textUri" >
</EditText>
```

this is my menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Search"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/edit">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/item_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_home"
    android:title="Home"
    app:showAsAction="always"></item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/item_pre"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_back"
    android:title="Back"
    app:showAsAction="always"></item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/item_forw"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_forw"
    android:title="Forward"
    app:showAsAction="always"></item>



</menu>
```

and this is my mainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar  mToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void initToolbar() {
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    mToolbar.setTitle("gnappo");
    mToolbar.showOverflowMenu();
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
}
}
```

thanks to advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go i solve your problem

**MainActivty.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pro.salman.toolbar.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:title="Forward"
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="100"/>



    <item
        android:title="Backward"
        android:id="@+id/backward"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="90"/>

    <item
        android:title="Home"
        android:id="@+id/Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="80"/>



    <item
        android:title="Search"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="70"/>

</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mEditText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)(findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        mEditText = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.editText));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setTitle("");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.search)
        {
            mEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**now result**

the edittext is hidden when user press the search button the edittext will show up

[image]

[image: when serach icon is pressed]

Comment: But when i add this line:-  setSupportActionBar(toolbar); then why my app crash?.i run this project in lolipop 5.1 ver.

Comment: check @user1992

Answer (score 2):

Salman500's answer is the best answer.just change your them in  res> values> style like this:-

```
 <style name="Appname" parent="Them.AppCompat.light.NoActionBar"
```

and enjoy.